Inkscape - How to create a grid inside shape where each cell is filled with a random unique color?
I am creating a figure for a paper and found out that Extensions->Render->Grids->Grid... allows a user to generate a grid inside any shape in Inkscape.
I would like to take it to the next level by adding random and unique colors for all cells in the grid. The reasoning behind it is that every cell represents a pixel with a unique ID:

As you can see I have a lot of cells and I have started colouring each (right). Even this number of cells is a rough depiction of what it actually should be (on th
If this is not possible, filling each with an ascending counter (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) would also do but colors are more impactful imho.

You can get part of the way by using Tiled clones
Random colours are certainly possible, but not both random and unique. Note to get this to work you have to set the fill of the initial square to "Unset Paint".
Here's an example using 30 x 30 tiles

You can also get unique colours (not random). The following example is a for 100 x 100 tiles. Here the HSL values are incremented by percentages. Obviously different numbers of tiles would require you to tweak the HSL percentages.

If you add a stroke colour to the initial square set to a "Flat" colour, and the fill colour set to "Unset Paint", the clones can then be created with a lined grid. The example below looks like it has black lines of different widths but that's not the actual case, just a crappy screen shot. Note also that this large number of clones will slow the Tiled clone generation down, and may slow Inkscape down considerably.

As far as I know there's nothing native in Inkscape that would allow you to automatically insert ascending numbers automatically into a grid pattern or tiles. This would likely require coding, which is generally off topic here.

A colleague also pointed out the Tiled feature and I couldn't find it. The issue was in my old version (provided by the Ubuntu 22.04 repos) so I had to do an upgrade and the Tiles were there. I will check the rest. Thanks for the feedback.

I've found an additional way you could actually create both randomised and unique coloured squares in a grid.
As in my previous answer

Create a square, set the fill to Paint Undefined

Use Tiled clones to create a grid, of unique colours.


Then continue as follows

Use the Align & Distribute panel, Align tab, and hit the Randomise Centres in Both Directions button in the Rearrange section

Move the black tile (the clone source with the undefined fill) well away from the random tiles, and select all the other tiles.

Switch to the Grid tab in the Align & Distribute panel, and set the number of columns and rows required, and choose Set Spacing, set X=0, Y=0, and hit apply


This will rearrange the randomised tiles back into a grid pattern.
An example using a 10 x 10 grid of cloned tiles


No step by step receipe here, but some easy to understand hints which may help if you cannot program a script which draws the needed squares in Inkscape or outputs a text file which contains the XML code of the wanted SVG image.
I made this Excel spreadsheet:

It was filled manually cell by cell, but an advanced Excel user  would generate the colors as random looking series of unique RGB codes in the same sheet elsewhere and then define the actual wanted area cell colors from these numbers by using Excel's functions. I have seen this asked numerous times in other websites and numerous answers were given. Harmfully they all looked too cryptic for me, but they were written by advanced Excel users for other advanced users, I guess.
The spreadsheet can be opied and pasted to Inkscape. Visually it looks perfect:

It's a vector - quite a surprise that Microsoft allows this to work! But ungrouping and moving some parts aside to see them better reveals that it's not as simple as it looks:

The gridlines are doubled and they are actually thin rectangles, not open lines. But it's a minor job to replace them with simple lines. It's probably better to remove all cell edges already in Excel. Harmfully there will still be some microscopic dots at cell corners and white cells get the edges anyway. To make it clean also the default worksheet grid must be disabled in Excel.
The cell color fills  - the thing you actually wanted - fortunately are perfectly aligned plain slightly overlapping rectangular paths which have just four sharp corner nodes. The overlapping can easily be fixed manually by scaling whole cell lines vertically and whole cell columns horizontally, if needed. So, this may solve your problem if you can fill a spreadsheet area with the wanted RGB numbers and apply those numbers to define cell colors of another area.
The numbers in the cells are simple text objects, one object per a cell, so this can also be used to make the optional "numeric only" fill.
I tested also how pasting from LibreOffice Calc works. The cell edges were misplaced in Inkscape and they were thin rectangles. But there was no microscopic corner dots and the cell fill color rectangles did not overlap. Cell content numbers came OK.
